# how do i align the center of some text to the bottom and center of an image with css

Tags: html, css

all of the methods I see can only center it to the bottom or the center, not both, and usually those methods mess with the scaling of the image

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="solar_website_css.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>the sun now</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="aia193im">
      <img src="https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_4096_0193.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="aia193txt">SDO AiA 193 Å </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.aia193im {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.aia193txt {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: bottom, center okay , but why vertical-align:middle in the code ? where do you want that text ? below or aside the image ? or is it on top ?

Comment: for some reason, i thought vertical-alignment: middle; meant the x-axis middle, not the y-axis middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more specific on where you want the text. If your desire is for the text to be centered *underneath* the image, to replicate a caption, place the items in a flex container, and align them center.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.figure {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.figure img {
 max-width: 90%;
 max-height: 90%;
}

.figure .caption {
 /* Stlye Caption Here */
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <img src="https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_4096_0193.jpg"/>
  <div class="caption">SDO AiA 193 Å</div>
</div>

<div class="figure">
  <img src="https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_4096_0193.jpg"/>
  <div class="caption">SDO AiA 193 Å</div>
</div>
```

Comment: although do you know a way to put text or an image on the screen that isn't in the flex column without disrupting the images/text that is in the flex column

Comment: also, why is the AIA 193 image offset from the top by a couple of pixels but when I add an image next to it it isn't offset at all (sorry if this all doesn't make any sense I'm still a CSS HTML noob)

Comment: If you could be more specific I could answer the question, what do you mean by "put image or text on a screen" without disrupting. 

Likewise maybe a picture you could add to the second question as well.

Comment: The spacing above the first figure is probably due to the padding and/or margin set on the parent element -- in the above snippet it would be the body element --.

Comment: ok thank you i found out that I could just set both images to Top: 0px; and then they are aligned. [the site is up now if you want to look at it](https://farm24.github.io/)